# Is there a way to replace a specific value with another value throughout a sqlite table?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

Don't know if I phrased it the right way, but for example:
How do I replace all the values "abc" with a value "efg" regardless of the column or row, I mean throughout the table in sqlite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a misconception here.
There are tables: defined by a set a fields (columns) and each table have records or data (rows).
If you want to modify all records for specific table, say 'foo':
You can code something like:

```py
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("UPDATE foo SET bar = REPLACE(bar, 'abc', 'efg'")
db.commit()
```

However, that will only modify data from column bar in table foo.
If you want to change all columns, you should loop and modify each column (same for each table).

[foo before replace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLI0I.png)

```py
cur.execute("SELECT c.name FROM pragma_table_info('foo') c");
cols = cur.fetchall()
for c in cols:
    cur.execute("UPDATE foo SET {} = REPLACE({}, 'abc', 'efg')".format(c[0], c[0]));  # ('colN',)
    db.commit()
```

[foo after replace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9aBo.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could replace by row for a specific column by using SQL:

```
update table
set col='efg'
where col='abc'
```

However, SQL is not set up to do that for every column.  You'd need something outside of SQL (say, a for loop in python) to do it for every column.